# Starter motor relay

Tags: electrical

I've had problems starting my 03 2-4 Accord, replaced starter after that the satnav would come on with the ignition but would go off after starting and stay off nothing on the display screen.just wondering if a new starter relay is the answer?

Comment: Starter or relay has nothing to do with satnav

Comment: So why does the satnav come on and then go off after starting the engine?

Comment: Does the screen lose power? What testing have you done so far? Why do you think the starter relay would be the answer?